# Using quotes around a nickname that's in the possessive

Tags: possessives, quotation-marks

I wanted to send a reading list to my dad about the state of the economy. One such commentator is known by the nickname "Dr. Doom". I went to write:

- *"Dr. Doom's" view is ...* **but that didn't look right because his name is Dr. Doom, not Dr. Doom's**, so I tried
- *"Dr. Doom"'s view is ...* **but that looked pretty terrible because I have three apostrophes in a row making it look like some crazy emoticon or something.**

This might not have a solution. My question is how to correctly use "double quotes" around "nouns" that are in the "possessive form"?

Comment: The question mark should go outside the quotes. Why are you quoting Dr. Doom's name?

Comment: Good question. I'm quoting it because it's not his real name, it's his kind of funny nickname. His real name is [Marc Faber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marc_Faber)

Comment: If you use quotation marks like `“` and `”` instead of `"`, they might look less like apostrophes to the reader.

Comment: @MattЭллен End-punctuation inside/outside closing quotes is a matter of style and differs.

Comment: "Dr. Doom's" is fine, is unambiguous, and most editors will pass it. If you are not constrained by a particular style guide, this would be your best bet. That's not a rule though, only a helpful tip, so this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: The objection that "his name is Dr. Doom, not Dr. Doom's" is understandable, but the inclusion of the possessive is allowed because it is not disparate from the name word. (You are only  modifying the word of the name into the possessive, not adding a new word.)

Answer (score 4):

The better question is, why are you putting the nickname in quotes at all? It is appropriate to do so the *first* time that you introduce a nickname, but subsequent uses do not require the quotes, and it clutters the story to use them every time. Do something like this:

> An unknown economist writing as "Dr. Doom" has chimed in. Dr. Doom's view is that...